# The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract come text between two tags. The "txtReadfile" contains many tags. I want to extract all the text in each occurrence of the tag.

I used the following code. but when I ran it, it gives the error:

```
Error # Error1 "The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments"
Error #  "Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string[]' "
```

Can you help me debug it?

```
List<string> destList = new List<string>();
string me = " <ts>(.*?)<t>";
string text =txtReadfile.Text;
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, me))
destList.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
string output= string.Join(" ", destList);
MessageBox.Show(output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
string output = string.Join(" ", destList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

Before .NET 4, the `String.Join` method only had overloads that took arrays as their second parameter. Support for `IEnumerable<string>` was only introduced in .NET 4.0.

```
// From .NET 2.0:
Join(String, String[])
Join(String, String[], Int32, Int32)
Join(String, Object[])

// From .NET 4.0:
Join(String, IEnumerable<String>)
Join<T>(String, IEnumerable<T>)
```

Thus, if you're targeting an earlier framework, you need to call `ToArray` on your list to convert it into `string[]`:

```
string output= string.Join(" ", destList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you are using .NET 3.5 or below. In this version `string.Join` only had [two overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

You need to convert your list to an array to be able to pass it in this version.

Simply use the [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819.aspx) method of `List<T>`:

```
string.Join(" ", destList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert it to `ToArray()`

```
string.join(" ",destList.ToArray());
```