# C# IEnumerable neededFiles

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
var neededFiles = new[]{ "file1.exe", "file2.exe", "file3.exe", "file4.exe" };

IEnumerable<string> notFound = neededFiles.Where(f => !File.Exists(f));
if (notFound.Any())
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format(notFound.Count() > 1 ?
        "App cannot find these files - {0}" :
        "App cannot find this file - {0}",
        String.Join(", ", neededFiles)), "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    return;
}
```

It work's OK, but If I have for example file1.exe, file2.exe, file3.exe files code anyway prints "App cannot find these files - file1.exe, file2.exe, file3.exe, file4.exe". *How to make it print only needed file which not exists*? Example: if exists **file1.exe**, **file3.exe**, it must print: App cannot find these files -  **file2.exe**, **file4.exe**
Thanks in advance

FIXED: [The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379077/the-best-overloaded-method-match-for-string-joinstring-string-has-some-in) This helped me.

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo. When doing `String.Join()`, you have to pass it `notFound` instead of `neededFiles`:

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Format(notFound.Count() > 1 ?
        "App cannot find these files - {0}" :
        "App cannot find this file - {0}",
        String.Join(", ", notFound)), "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

Comment: Are you sure that file1.exe, file2.exe and file3.exe are in you application's working directory? This should be working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `String.Join(", ", notFound)`, instead of `String.Join(", ", neededFiles)`.

Comment: I've tried it, but its same :( These strings: "App cannot find these files - {0}" : "App cannot find this file - {0}" chages, but files not :/

Comment: Translated with google...

The argument of "2": type conversion of "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable <string>" to "string []" is impossible

Comment: And "The most appropriate method for the supercharged "string.Join (string, string [])" has some invalid arguments"

Comment: P.S Fixed, It will helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379077/the-best-overloaded-method-match-for-string-joinstring-string-has-some-in

Comment: Yes, `notFound.ToArray()` should work, but I wonder why you don't have `Join()` overload that also takes `IEnumerable<string>`. You're on some older .NET version maybe?