# select from list using LINQ's Where

Tags: c#, linq

I need to get the vehicle type according to vehicle number. I need to select specific column from a list according to another column.

Here is my code:

```
protected void ddVehicleNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Exp_VehicleDTO> odata = (List<Exp_VehicleDTO>)Session["VehicleDTO"];
    var vehityeps=odata.Select(x=>x.VehicleNo.Contains(x.VehicleType.Equals(Convert.ToInt32(ddVehicleNo.SelectedValue))))
}
```

This code causes error "the best overload method match for "string.contains(string)" has some invalid arguments".

Exp_vehicleDTO class

```
public class Exp_VehicleDTO
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public int VehicleId { get; set; }

    public int VehicleType { get; set; }

    public string VehicleNo { get; set; }

    public int Status { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    public string CreatedMachine { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting, add information to the question

Comment: this causes error "the best overload method match for "string.contains(string)" has some invalid arguments"

Comment: `x.VehicleType.Equals` returns a boolean, you're now trying to find a boolean value in a string (VehicleNo). When you see that kind of error message, examine the method you're using and the information you're putting into it carefully.

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32` is your actual problem

Comment: `Equals` returns a `bool` yet `Contains` expects a `string`.

Comment: `odata.Where(x=>x.VehicleNo == VehicleNo.SelectedValue && x.VehicleType == somethingWhoKnows))` maybe?

Comment: i just need to filter the vehicle type according to provided vehicle number which i select from vehicle number combo box. when i select a vehicle number from combo box, the relevant vehicle type should be selected from vehicle type combo box.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string\[\])' has some invalid arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24379077/the-best-overloaded-method-match-for-string-joinstring-string-has-some-in)

Comment: yes i did a mistake by converting to int32. now i fixed it, but my requirement does not fulfilled yet

Comment: @TheGeneral nope. it does not work

Comment: Yeah the bigmistake of this question was not giving your data types, and exactly what you wanted to return. though i was amused for 5 mintues.. job done

Comment: "i did a mistake by converting to int32. " that is not the main mistake. If you want to filter you should use `Where` and not `Select`, otherwise you get a collection of `bool` values. and `Contains` needs a `string` as input

Comment: Separate your problem into 3 parts: 1) Get the correct vehicle object from the list using `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, or `SingleOrDefault`. 2) Extract the Vehicle type from the vehicle object. 3) Find the corresponding item in the combo box and set that to the selected item.

Comment: @Didu - You're also not doing anything with the `Select`. It's hard to know how to help you without the proper types and what you're intending to do with this query.

Comment: @John yes that was helpful. i can do the 1st and 3rd part. the problem is i don't have a clear idea about how to do the 2nd part.

Comment: please post the code for `Exp_VehicleDTO`

Comment: @Didu `int vehicleType = odata.Single(x => x.VehicleNo.Equals(ddVehicleNo.SelectedValue)).VehicleType` (note this will throw an exception if the vehicle doesn't exist, or there is more than 1 vehicle with the same vehicleNo)

Comment: @John yes it woked. thank u mate :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the vehicle type like so:

```
int vehicleType = odata.Single(x => x.VehicleNo.Equals(ddVehicleNo.SelectedValue)).VehicleType;
```

`Single` will take the first item that matches the condition. Note that it will throw an exception if the item isn't found, or if there are multiple matching items.

If you want to handle the case that the item isn't found, you can do something like this:

```
var vehicle = odata.SingleOrDefault(x => x.VehicleNo.Equals(ddVehicleNo.SelectedValue));
if (vehicle != null)
{
    var vehicleType = vehicle.VehicleType;
}
else
{
    // set combobox's SelectedIndex to -1
}
```

Comment: how can i modify this to avoid exeption if the item isn't found?

Comment: @Didu updated :-) You can also swap `Single`/`SingleOrDefault` for `First`/`FirstOrDefault` if you expect multiple items might have the same `VehicleNo` and you just want the first one.

Comment: Works fine. thank you very much :)

Comment: It was a long road, but someone got there in the end, up vote

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to help without knowing what error you are receiving but try changing your code to this:

```
protected void ddVehicleNo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Exp_VehicleDTO> odata = (List<Exp_VehicleDTO>)Session["VehicleDTO"];

    var vehityeps = odata
        .Where(v => v.VehicleNo.ToString() == ddVehicleNo.SelectedValue)
        .Select(v => v.VehicleType);
}
```

That should populate `vehityeps` with all `VehicleType`'s where `VehicleNo` equals what the user has selected in the `ddVehicleNo` drop down.

**UPDATED**

I'm not sure what types are used `Exp_VehicleDTO` but my guess is `VehicleNo` is an `int`. To be safe with my solution this compares the values as strings.

Comment: but this gives a type conversion error

Comment: @Didu remove `int.Parse(  )` around `ddVehicleNo.SelectedValue` - Jesse has assumed it's int since you didn't post your class definition on this question.

Comment: done. but it recieves cannot implicity convert type string to bool

Comment: @John thanks for clarifying to @Didu the assumption of an `int`. The assumption is based on `Convert.ToInt32(ddVehicleNo.SelectedValue)` from the code within the question.

Comment: I would have made the same assumption :-)